# Trouble with my code - can't get it to replace items in queue visually?

Tags: vb.net

Okay, so I'm making a representation of a queue system, for example at a school. I'm having huge problems. 
I have small textboxes representing members of the queue, but when I try to remove a diner, and move the others forward to replace it, it just doesn't work. 
It just deletes the visual representation of the text box I wanted it to replace, and the other textboxes just stay stagnant, they don't move up in the queue. I know I'm probably being a complete fool, but I just can't make it work. I've tried a lot of variations and I'm getting desperate.

Here's some of the variables each Diner has:

```
  Public Sub New(ByRef AnyForm As Form)
    Me.VisRep = New TextBox
    Me.VisRep.Multiline = True
    Me.YearGroup = GenerateYearGroup()

    Me.PriorityValue = SetPriority()
    Me.VisRep.BackColor = GetBackgroundColour()
    Me.VisRep.ForeColor = Color.White
    Me.VisRep.Text = Me.YearGroup
    Me.MoneyOnCard = MoneyOnDinerCard()
```

When the Queue is drawn, this procedure is called:

```
      Public Sub DrawQueue()
    Dim TempPoint As Point
    TempPoint = Me.StartPoint
    TempPoint.X += 70

    For looper = 0 To LooperNumber

        Sandpit.Controls.Add(Me.QueueMembers(looper).VisRep)
        Me.QueueMembers(looper).VisRep.ForeColor = Me.QueueMembers(looper).GetBackgroundColour
        Select Case (Me.Direction)
            Case "R"
                TempPoint.X += 32
                TempPoint.Y = 260
            Case "U"
                TempPoint.Y += 32
            Case "L"
                TempPoint.X -= 32
        End Select
        Me.QueueMembers(looper).VisRep.SetBounds(TempPoint.X, TempPoint.Y, 30, 30)
    Next
End Sub
```

The code I use to Shuffle the queue forward - or that I'm trying to use - is this:

```
Public Sub ShuffleAllForward()
    For looper = 0 To Me.EndPointer
        If Diner.PositionInQueue = 0 Then
            RemoveDiner()
            QueueMembers(looper) = QueueMembers(looper + 1)

        Else
            Diner.PositionInQueue -= 1
        End If
      Next
      DrawQueue()
   End Sub
```

and the Remove Diner it calls is:

```
   Public Sub RemoveDiner()
    Dim TempDiner As Diner
    For looper = 0 To Me.EndPointer - 1
        TempDiner = QueueMembers(looper)
        QueueMembers(looper) = QueueMembers(looper + 1)
    Next
    Diner.PositionInQueue -= 1
    Me.EndPointer -= 1
    LooperNumber -= 1
    DrawQueue()
End Sub
```

I just can't get it to work. I know I'm probably being a complete idiot, but I'm just trying to improve my coding ability and I'm not doing well.

Any help would just be really appreciated, and I would be so grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to put a Me.Refresh() at the end of the drawing?

Comment: I tried, but the DrawQueue() sub is in a class I created. I put it on the form, but it did nothing.

Comment: Creating and moving TBs is a very expensive implementation.  Something like this is usually implemented with 2 classes once for the Item and a Collection Class to manage the lot of them (which might use an actual Queue collection).  A scrollable panel would eliminate all the move up move dn code and you'd just  Add new ones and remove the top one.